# JSON object: Query a value from unkown node based on a condition

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying to query two values (`DISCOUNT_TOTAL` and `ITEM_TOTAL`) from a JSON object in a PostgreSQL database. Take the following query as reference:

```
SELECT
    mt.customer_order
    totals -> 0 -> 'amount' -> centAmount DISCOUNT_TOTAL
    totals -> 1 -> 'amount' -> centAmount ITEM_TOTAL
FROM
    my_table mt
    to_jsonb(my_table.my_json -> 'data' -> 'order' -> 'totals') totals
WHERE
    mt.customer_order in ('1000001', '1000002')
```

The query code works just fine, the big problem is that, for some reason out of my control, the values `DISCOUNT_TOTAL` and `ITEM_TOTAL` some times change their positions in the JSON object from one `customer_order` to other:

[JSON Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTFNh.png)

So i cannot aim to `totals -> 0 -> 'amount' -> centAmount` assuming that it contains the value related to `type : DISCOUNT_TOTAL` (same for `type: ITEM_TOTAL`). Is there any work around to get the correct `centAmount` for each `type`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a path query instead of hardcoding the array positions:

```
with sample (jdata) as (
values (
'{
    "data": {
        "order": {
            "email": "something",
            "totals": [
                {
                    "type": "ITEM_TOTAL",
                    "amount": {
                        "centAmount": 14990
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "DISCOUNT_TOTAL",
                    "amount": {
                        "centAmount": 6660
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}'::jsonb)
)
select jsonb_path_query_first(
          jdata, 
         '$.data.order.totals[*] ? (@.type == "DISCOUNT_TOTAL").amount.centAmount'
       ) as discount_total,
       jsonb_path_query_first(
          jdata, 
         '$.data.order.totals[*] ? (@.type == "ITEM_TOTAL").amount.centAmount'
       ) as item_total
  from sample;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=973a0b9f5d973611bf79f9c6d188a0e5)*

**EDIT:**  In case your PostgreSQL version does not support json path queries, you can do it by expanding the array into rows and then doing a pivot by `case` and `sum`:

```
with sample (order_id, jdata) as (
values ( 1, 
'{
    "data": {
        "order": {
            "email": "something",
            "totals": [
                {
                    "type": "ITEM_TOTAL",
                    "amount": {
                        "centAmount": 14990
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "DISCOUNT_TOTAL",
                    "amount": {
                        "centAmount": 6660
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}'::jsonb)
)
select order_id, 
       sum(
         case
           when el->>'type' = 'DISCOUNT_TOTAL' then (el->'amount'->'centAmount')::int
           else 0
         end 
       ) as discount_total,
       sum(
         case
           when el->>'type' = 'ITEM_TOTAL' then (el->'amount'->'centAmount')::int
           else 0
         end 
       ) as item_total
  from sample
       cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(jdata->'data'->'order'->'totals') as a(el)
 group by order_id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2d5bd1b7603ef05523aab7c4af8db3a5)*

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Mike! Sadly, it seems to me that we are using an older version (PostgreSQL 11.16) that doesn't support the  **jsonb_path_query_first** function. Do I have another option?

Comment: @CristianCastillo  Why, yes.  Yes, you do.  Give me about fifteen minutes, and I will @ you after I update my answer.

Comment: @CristianCastillo  I added an example of how it was done prior to version 12.

Comment: You're the best, man! Thanks a million, i'm really grateful.